# FsCheck InvalidCastException

Tags: testing, f#, xunit, fscheck

Upon running with xUnit the simplest test from FsCheck

```
open FsCheck

[<Property>]
let revRevIsOrig (xs:list<int>) = 
        List.rev(List.rev xs) = xs
```

I receive the exception

```
---- System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'FsList@303[System.Int32]' 
to type 'FsCheck.Arbitrary`1[Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[System.Int32]]'.
```

I tried to catch the exception and debug, but occurs before
Would anyone have any clue on how to solve this ?

**Way to reproduce:**

- make a new project
- install FsCheck.xUnit NUget
- put that code into the fs file
- run the tests

Comment: bindingRedirect probably missing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11718385/system-wide-bindingredirect-for-f-4-0-0-0-to-4-3-0-0

Comment: Argh! You must be right.

Comment: that was it. new library, new machine, new country = too much to handle ! I had never seen this kind of error though, what put you on the way ?